# Crystal Report in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crosstab

Im creating a report using crystal report in vb.net.

The report contained a crosstab which I have 3 data:
1. Dealer - row field
2. Month - column
3. Quantity Sales - summarize field

How can I arrange this by ascending order based on the 
Quantity Sales - summarize field?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you're working with it, you can adjust the input to order the data ascending.

> ```
> SELECT customer, sum(amountdue) AS total FROM invoices 
> GROUP BY customer
> ORDER BY total ASC
> ```

If you're doing in a way that you can't change that information, could you provide a little more insight?

Answer (score 0):

Note that other Business Objects products order on the total of a summary field when sorting a cross tab by it's values.  I forget how CR does it exactly.